# Error handling with int32.TryParse

Tags: c#, error-handling

I am having trouble with adding a error message and a reloop on this and wonder how I can add "Wrong input, try again" and then try to write down the correct numbers. It doesn't crash, that's good so far but I would like to have an error without using try and catch and a loop that forces you to write only numbers to be correct.

Here's the code I've done so far:

```
bool loopie = true;
int result;
int result2;
int result3;

while (loopie)
{

    Console.Write("Number one: ");             
    Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result);

    Console.WriteLine(" ");
    Console.Write("Number two: ");
    Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result2);

    Console.WriteLine(" ");
    Console.Write("Number two: ");
    Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result3);

    Console.WriteLine(" ");
    int summa = result + result2 + result3;
    Console.WriteLine("summan: " + summa);

}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Your title already says that you want to use `TryParse`... what do you need us for then?

Comment: Aside: you have two `Console.Write("Number two: ");` calls.

Comment: `TryParse` returns bool. use that ;)

Comment: `Int32.TryParse` returns a `bool`. That is, true if the parse was successful, false if it was not. So you should use `if(Int32.TryParse("", out result)){...} else { Console.WriteLine("Error parsing number"); }`

Comment: Rewriting it atm and I forgot that you use a bool, now I just need to make it to retry after a fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TryParse returns bool that specifies if conversion done correctly or not. so use it.

```
while (loopie)
{
    Console.Write("Number one: ");
    if (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong input. try again.");
        continue;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(" ");
    Console.Write("Number two: ");
    if (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result2))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong input. try again.");
        continue;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(" ");
    Console.Write("Number two: ");
    if (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result3))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong input. try again.");
        continue;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(" ");
    int summa = result + result2 + result3;
    Console.WriteLine("summan: " + summa);
}
```

Or use another while if you dont want to reset whole process after fail.

```
do  
{
    Console.Write("Number one: ");
    Console.WriteLine("Wrong input. try again.");
} while (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result)); // write this for all 3 inputs.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int result, result2, result3;

private int GetResult(string msg)
{
    int temp;

    do
    {
       Console.Write(msg);
    }
    while(!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out temp));

    return temp;
}

void Main()
{
   var result = GetResult("Number one:");
   var result2 = GetResult("Number two:");
   var result3 = GetResult("Number three:");

   Console.WriteLine("summan: " + (result + result2 + result3).ToString());
}
```

If we wanted to be even more 'elegant' (at the cost of readability - and ability to use the value of the `result` variables later on):

```
void Main()
{
   Console.WriteLine("summan: " + (GetResult("Number one:") +                     
                                   GetResult("Number two:") +         
                                   GetResult("Number three:")).ToString());
}
```